# React-native-fbsdk building error

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I am using to react-native-fbsdk. But last time when i tried to build my project on Android I have this error.

```
  Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':react-native-fbsdk:_debugPublishCopy'.
     > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1.
       Searched in the following locations:
           file:/home/deema/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.1.pom
           file:/home/deema/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.1.jar
           file:/home/deema/Desktop/work/projects/dacebookTest/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.1.jar
       Required by:
           dacebookTest:react-native-fbsdk:unspecified
     > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1.
```

There are more same errors with com.android.support v 27.
I tried to create new empty project and I have same errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/build.gradle
```

with

```
compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0')
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is in the error message shown in your case:

> Searched in the following locations:
>   `file:/home/deema/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/`

I have had the same. Then I went to the location:

> file:/home/deema/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/

And found that there is no directory named `27.0.1` because in my case the latest buildTool was not downloaded. In my case I have had `27.0.0-alpha1`.

So in both of my app `build.gradle` and in

> node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/build.gradle

And replaced `27.0.1` with `27.0.0-alpha1` and build was successful.